# Combinatorial solution to a recurrence problem

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I found today this problem in some old blog post:

Suppose that $a_n$ is a sequence of positive integers such that
$$ \sum_{d |n} a_d =2^n$$ for every positive integer $n$. Prove that $ n | a_n$.

It seems like a sort of induction could work (working with prime divisors, etc...), but I am interested in a different, and possibly more elegant solution:

> In my notes I have written that this has a **combinatorial** solution, but I can't seem to figure it out now. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the highest term in the sum is linearly determined by all the lower ones, and $a_1=2$ (as Brian pointed out), this is a recurrence relation that uniquely determines all $a_n$. Thus it suffices to exhibit a sequence that fulfills the recurrence relation.

The right-hand side counts the number of binary sequences of length $n$. The left-hand side counts these sequences according to their (primitive cyclical) periods $d$, which must divide $n$. The number of sequences with period $d$ is divisible by $d$, since each sequence is in an equivalence class of $d$ sequences related by shifts.

Note that this works because the number $a_d$ of sequences with period $d$ is independent of their length $n$ and depends only on $d$.

Comment: Since $2^1=\sum_{d\mid 1}a_d$, you must have $a_1=2$.

Comment: @Brian: Ah yes :-)

Comment: That's what I was going to say. It is a cool solution.

Comment: @Beni: See [OEIS A027375](http://oeis.org/A027375) and [OEIS A001037](http://oeis.org/A001037).

Answer (score 2):

By Möbius inversion formula, we have that
$$a_n = \sum_{d \vert n} \mu(d) 2^{n/d} = n M_n(2)$$
where $M_n(2)$ is the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

And look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152880/how-many-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-n-exist-over-mathbbf-p) why $\displaystyle n \vert \sum_{d \vert n} \mu(d) 2^{n/d}$

Comment: Is this a combinatorial solution?

Comment: @joriki The answer shows that $\dfrac{a_n}n$ counts the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over the ﬁeld of two elements and hence I believe is a combinatorial solution.

Comment: A combinatorial solution isn't a solution that shows that something counts some number, but one that shows something by counting. What you mean is sort of the dual of a combinatorial solution, an analytic solution to a combinatorial problem.

Comment: Usually Mobius inversion is tied to combinatorics. It is not what I had in mind, but is is still a nice solution. Thanks