# Is generic polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$ for very big $p$ irreducible?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, irreducible-polynomials

1.Let us consider the set $F[x]_{n,k}$ of all polynomials over $F$ of degree $n$ having preciesly $k$ irreducible factors. The question is: Fix some $n$. Let $p$ be a big prime number.How the cardinality of the sets $\mathbb F_p[x]_{n,k}, 1\leq k\leq n$ looks like? Is it true that $|\mathbb F_p[x]_{n,1}|>0.99\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\mathbb F_p[x]_{n,k}|$ when $p$ is very big?

Can we compute the limit of $\dfrac{|\mathbb F_p[x]_{n,j}|}{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\mathbb F_p[x]_{n,k}|}$ for fixed $j,n$ when $p\to +\infty$?

Comment: Did you ever see $\sum_{d| n} \mu(d) p^{n/d}$ ? It is the number of elements of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ whose $\Bbb{F}_p$-minimal polynomial has degree $n$. From its obvious asymptotic $p^n+O(p^{n/2} \tau(n))$ you can find the asymptotic of your sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

In fact, there is a formula (in terms of [mobius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) and the [mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) $\mu$) for the number of monic irreducibles of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$:

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) p^{n/d}
$$

You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152880/how-many-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-n-exist-over-mathbbf-p) for a more detailed discussion of this formula.

In the case $n$ is prime, this has a simpler closed form (since the divisors $d \mid n$ are easy to understand):

$$
\frac{p^n - p}{n}
$$

(again, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-prime-degree-p-over-finite-fields) for a more detailed discussion).

Since there are $p^n$ many monic polynomials of degree $n$, this tells us that the fraction of irreducible polynomials (if we continue assuming $n$ is prime, for simplicity) is:

$$\frac{1}{n} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{p^{n-1}} \right )$$

Which, for large $p$, is roughly $1/n$.

With a little bit more work, you can use this same formula in order to compute the asymptotic size of your sets of interest.

---

I hope this helps ^_^