# There is no irreducible polynomial of largest degree in $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am asked to prove or disprove that given a finite field $\mathbf{F}_q$, the ring $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$ contains irreducible polynomials of arbitrarily large degree. I couldn't think of a reason why this should be false so I tried to prove it. Inspired by Euclid:

> Take arbitrary $\mathbf{F}_{q}$. Consider $X_{n}=\{f\in\mathbf{F}_{q}[x]:f\;\text{irreducible}, 1\leqslant\deg f\leqslant n\}$ (finite). Define:
>   $$h(x)=\prod_{f\in X_n} f(x)+1$$
>   Then $\deg h>n$ and $h\in \mathbf{F}_q[x]$ irreducible.

Does this work? If not any pointers/should I be proving the opposite?

Comment: You can't conclude that $h$ is irreducible, but you can surely say that it has an irreducible factor of degree $> n$. By arbitrarity of $n$, you are done.

Comment: $h$ is not necessarily irreducible, but it is not divisible by any of the $f\in X_n$. I think you can't really avoid an argument by contradiction (if there was a largest degree, then $X_n$ would consist of all irreducible polynomials for some $n$), but the idea is very nice indeed.

Comment: More can be said.  There exists an irreducible polynomial of every positive integer degree over a finite field.

Comment: See for example [Counting Irreducible Polynomials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92747/counting-irreducible-polynomials)  over a finite field.

Comment: Thanks all, I can see now that $h$ is not necessarily irreducible (much like $\prod p + 1$ is not necessarily prime in Euclid's proof) but that it is sufficient to guarantee the existence of an irreducible of higher degree.