# How many completely reducible polynomials of degree $n$ are there in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials, asymptotics

What do we know about the count of completely reducible polynomials modulo $p$?  In other words, polynomials that factor into all linear factors and nothing of higher degree.

From this site and regarding *irreducible* polynomials, we have:

1. ["Counting Irreducible Polynomials"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/92747/2626)
2. [IBS's answer to "Number of monic irreducible polynomials of prime degree p over finite fields"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40875/2626)

What we can say, if anything, about (completely or totally) *reducible* polynomials?  More specifically, in the case where we have degree $n$ polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: By *completely reducible* you mean that the polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors?

Comment: @SammyBlack: Yes.

Comment: Yes, I didn't read "completely" in your question at first, and deleted my comment. I added that word to the title of your post for clarity.

Comment: Well, how many multisets of size $n$ can you make out of $p$ elements?

Comment: @lulu:  $p^n$?  I'm not sure where you're going with this.

Comment: @lulu:  So $p$ is the number of unique linear factors?

Comment: $p$ is the order of the field, as you indicated.

Comment: I'm not saying anything complicated...sticking to monic polynomials for the moment, such a thing is determined by the list of its roots with multiplicity.  That means, a multiset of size $n$.  Then, of course, you have to multiply by the number of possible lead coefficients ($p-1$).

Comment: So I guess each of the field elements makes a linear factor, and we can create $p^n$ different reducible polynomials out of these linear factors!  That's pretty cool...  I keep thinking that some of them will make the same polynomial, though.

Comment: I have no idea where you are getting $p^n$.  You have to count the multisets, for which, see [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.)

Comment: A completely reducible polynomial of degree $n>0$ has precisely $n$ roots in $\Bbb{F}_p$. In how many ways can you distribute these $n$ roots among the $p$ possible values? Conversely every completely reducible polynomial is determined (up to scaling) by its roots, counting multiplicity.

Comment: Thank you two very much.  I'll upvote if you want to write up an answer.  I hope I haven't ruined this site too much, I just couldn't come up with this on my own.

Comment: Feel free to post a solution once you've worked it through.  I'll review it, if you like (don't forget to use the @ symbol so that the intended user gets the message).

Comment: @lulu:  I posted an answer, which seems to agree with Sammy Black.  Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Your post looks good (+1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely reducible *monic* polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ are in bijective correspondence with the multiset of their roots (multiplicity counts number of linear factors for each root). Factoring in terms of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p = \{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}$, this bijection looks like
\begin{align} 
(x - 0)^{m_0} \cdot (x - 1)^{m_1} \cdots (x - (p-1))^{m_{p-1}} 
\quad&\longleftrightarrow\quad 
\{ 0^{m_0},  1^{m_1}, \dots, (p-1)^{m_{p-1}} \} \\
\quad&\longleftrightarrow\quad 
(m_0, m_1, \dots, m_{p-1}) 
\end{align}
where each $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and the total degree is
$m_0 + m_1 + \cdots + m_{p-1} = n$.

Enumerating the latter ([multiset coefficient](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multiset#/Counting_multisets)) is a well-known combinatorics exercise
$$
\left(\!\!\left( \begin{matrix} 
p \\ n 
\end{matrix} \right)\!\!\right) 
= \binom{p+n-1}{n}
$$

If you want to allow any nonzero leading coefficient, then you need to multiply the answer by $(p-1)$, since any nonzero leading coefficient is possible and determines a distinct polynomial.

Comment: I'm now seeing that people have been working this out with OP in the comments. Feel free to hold off and choose one of their answers if they post. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the fact that we're working in $\mathbb{F}_p$.  There are $p$ different elements, each of which we can call $a$ to create a linear factor $x-a$.

Next, we want to create a polynomial using only these linear factors.  We want to create a size $n$ polynomial, and we will use exactly $n$ of our linear factors with repetition allowed.

This is precisely the "stars-and-bars" problem from combinatorics.  We have $p$ different locations, which are separated using $p-1$ bars.  Then we place $n$ stars into whichever locations we like, and we can place more than one in each location.  For example, if we have $p=5$ locations and an $n=3$ degree polynomial, one possible solution is:

$$ | \star \star || \star |$$

You can see more on this at [Wikipedia's "Stars and bars (combinatorics)" page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

The result is

$$\binom{n + p - 1}{n} \text { or } \binom{n + p - 1}{p-1}$$

Comment: Don't forget that you need to consider the possible lead coefficients.  There are $p-1$ of these, so multiply your result by $p-1$.

Comment: @lulu:  Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that I was thinking about monic polynomials.  Good point!