# Monic Irreducible Polynomials over Finite Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, mobius-inversion

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a finite field (so $q=p^k$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $k$), and let $\varphi(d)$ denote the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ in $F[X]$. I'm supposed to show that $\displaystyle{\sum_{d \mid n} d \varphi(d) = q^n}$.

I see there are previous questions about this topic and even a paper, but all (save one) seem to employ the use of the Möbius function and Möbius inversion - both topics I have not covered yet in class. There is also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-p-over-finite-fields), but it appears to hinge upon the extension having prime degree. Is there some way to show this without explicitly coming up with a formula for the number of irreducible monic polynomials of a given degree in $F[X]$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider elements $\alpha\in F$ and their minimal polynomials $m_\alpha(x)$ over the prime field. What degrees are possible for $m_\alpha$? Why do they all appear as $m_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$? How many elements of $F$ share the same minimal polynomial? Derive an equation!

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb F(q^r)\subset\mathbb F(q^s)$ if and only if $r|s$?

Comment: As an aside, Mobius inversion is employed *after* that formula is already attained (to find $\varphi$ explicitly) - it is not used *to* obtain it.

Comment: @Lubin, Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{q^r} \subset \mathbb{F}_{q^s}$ iff $r \mid s$? If so, then yes, I do know that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, For any $\alpha \in F$, $m_\alpha (x) = x - \alpha$, and distinct minimal polynomials do not share common roots, so $\sum_{\alpha \in F} \# m_{\alpha} = q$. I think I see what you're getting at now.

Comment: Joe, $m_\alpha$ is not the minimal polynomial over $F$, but over the prime field of $p$ elements. Nevertheless, they do not share roots, but have as many roots as is indicated by their degree.

Comment: Whoopsie. Ok. So, $\deg m_\alpha(x)$ can be $p, p^2, \ldots, p^{k}=q$. Since distinct minimal polynomials do not share common roots, that leaves $p^{k-1}$ distinct minimal polynomials of degree $p$, and only $1$ of degree $q$, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The splitting field of $X^{q^n}-X$ is ${\bf F}_{q^n}$. Every irreducible $\pi(X)$ of degree $d$ splits in ${\bf F}_{q^n}$ and every element of ${\bf F}_{q^n}$ is a root of $X^{q^n}-X$, and thus $\pi(X)\mid(X^{q^n}-X)$. Furthermore $X^{q^n}-X$ has no repeated roots so each irreducible $\pi(X)$ of degree $d\mid n$ must appear in its factorization precisely once. Therefore we have the conclusion

$$X^{q^n}-X=\prod_{d\mid n}\prod_{\deg\pi=d}\pi(X).$$

Taking degrees yields $\displaystyle q^n=\sum_{d\mid n}d\varphi(d)$ (and from here Möbius inversion yields $\varphi(d)$).

Comment: Somehow it wasn't clicking that I was examining polynomial degrees. When you put it that way, it's quite clear to me now what is happening.