# number of quadratic Ireducible Polynomial over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: finite-fields

Could anyone help me : What is the way of finding the number of Ireducible quadratic Polynomial over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Thank you for help.

Comment: There are infinitely many irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb F_2$. You need to edit your question to ask about some finite subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general answer, see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40811/15941).

For your particular problem, just make a list of the four quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb F_2[x]$ and figure out how many of them are reducible. Then count the rest
to come up with the answer.   (Hint: $x^2+1 = (x+1)^2$ in $\mathbb F_2[x]$.)

Comment: In fact you don't even have to directly count how many are reducible -- you can count how many ways there are to multiply two linear polynomials together!

Answer (score 3):

An irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ has a conjugate pair of roots in $\mathbb{F}_4$ that are not in any proper subfield of $\mathbb{F}_4$. ($\mathbb{F}_2$ is the only proper subfield)

So how many elements are there in $\mathbb{F}_4$ that aren't in any subfield? How many conjugacy classes are there?