# polynomials over finite field with irreducible factors of odd degrees

Tags: polynomials, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

It is well-known that the number of monic $n$-degree polynomials over a finite field of size $q$ is $q^n$. How many such degree-$n$ polynomials can be completely factored into only irreducible polynomials of odd degree? Does anyone know of any related literature?

Comment: I think you could use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-p-over-finite-fields?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what type of answer is desired (estimating the number of such polynomials, or giving a formula for this number, or...).  I just want to remark here that one can approach this question via generating functions.
Write $O_n$ for the number of monic degree-$n$ polynomials in $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$ which have only odd-degree irreducible factors, and $I_n$ for the number of monic degree-$n$ irreducible polynomials in $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$.  Then $O_n$ is the sum, over all partitions $1\le a_1\le a_2\le...$ of $n$ into odd parts, of the product
$I_{a_1} \cdot I_{a_2} \cdot ...$.  Now write
$$
I(t) = \sum_{\substack{i>0 \\ i \text{ odd}}} I_i t^i \quad\text{ and }\quad O(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} O_i t^i
$$
where $t$ is a formal variable.  Then the above identity for $O_n$ becomes
$$
O(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} I(t)^k = -1 + \frac{1}{1-I(t)}.
$$
This formulation has the advantage of compactly recording the known information.  In some sense, since we know the coefficients of $I(t)$, we also know $O(t)$... although whether this helps resolve a specific question about $O(t)$ will depend on the question.