# Number of irreducible quadratic polynomials over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields, quadratics, irreducible-polynomials

To  find  the  number  of  irreducible  polynomials of  the  form $x^{2} + ax+b$  over  the  field  $\Bbb{F}_{7}$  I  manually  checked  all  the  possibilities  and  thus  found  the  answer  to  be  $21.$ Like $b=0$  is  not  possible  or  taking  $b=1$  and  checking  what  values  of $a$  works  here  etc. Surely it  was   tedious  and  time-consuming  process  and  I  don't  think  it  was  appropriate  either. For  what  should  be  done for  a much  larger  field$?$  Are  there  some  basic  theories  that  I  should  use. Hints  please.

Comment: You may want to check out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101464/the-number-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-mathbb-f-p

Comment: To count, find the number of monic **reducibles**.  That's easy, they are $(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a,b$ are distinct or equal.

Comment: Let the field have $N$ elements. There are $N^2$ monic quadratics, and $\binom{N}{2}+N$ reducibles among them, so $N(N-1)/2$ irreducibles.

Comment: The formula for the number of irreducible polynomials over a finite field and of a given degree has appeared on our site many times. [Go ahead and search!](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[finite-fields]+number+of+irreducible+polynomials)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Regardless of the  field, if  a monic polynomial $$x^2+ax+b$$ is given then it can be reducible in two different ways:

$$(x-p)(x-q);p\neq q\\\text{or}\\(x-p)(x-q)={(x-p)}^2;p=q$$

If the  field   has  cardinality  $N$, then the total  number  of  quadratic  monic  polynomials  is  $N^2$.  There  are $\binom{N}{2}$ (Combination without repetition)  ways  of  choosing $\{p,q\}$ in the first case and $N$  ways in the second. We can conclude that the number  of reducible  polynomials  is  $${\binom{N}{2}}+N\\={{{N(N+1)}}\over 2}$$
So  the  number  of  irreducible polynomials  is  $$N^2-{{{N(N+1)}}\over 2}\\=N\cdot{{N-1}\over 2}$$

Since $N$ was arbitrary the claim follows.

Answer (score 5):

The number of monic quadratic polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_q$ is $q^2$; they are the polynomials
$$X^2+aX+b,$$
with $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_q$. If a monic quadratic polynomial $P\in\Bbb{F}_q[X]$ is reducible then
$$P(X)=(X-a)(X-b),$$
for some $a,b\in\Bbb{F}_q$. So how many reducible monic quadratic polynomials are there?

> There are $\tfrac{1}{2}q(q+1)$ reducible monic quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_q$.
>  This yields a total of $\tfrac{1}{2}q(q-1)$ irreducible monic quadratic polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_q[X]$. For $q=7$ we indeed get $21$ such polynomials.

Comment: I like your use of "invisible ink" - it's great pedagogical tool.

Answer (score 1):

In any field (characteristic $\neq 2$) the quadratic formula still holds.  The equation: $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ has **two** solutions:

$$ x = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}$$

Then as $(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}_7^2$ how many of these have $a^2 - 4b$ a quadratic residue?  Since $4$ is invertible mod $7$

$$ a^2 - 4 \,\mathbb{F}_7 = \mathbb{F}_7$$

If we replace $7$ with a large prime $p \gg 1$ the odds of being a quadratic residue approach $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

What does the quadratic formula look like in characteristic 2?  In $\mathbb{F}_2$ it is easy enough to check by hand.  There are also finite fields with $2^n$ elements such as $\mathbb{F}_8$ which are also characteristic 2.

See also: **[Number of monic irreducible polynomials of prime degree $p$ over finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-p-over-finite-fields)**

Comment: What about fields of characteristic $2$? And I don't see how this answers the question exactly...

Comment: In $\mathbb{F}_2$, there are only 4 possibilities $x^2 , x^2 + 1=(x+1)^2, \color{blue}{x^2 + x + 1}, x^2 + x = x(x+1)$

Comment: I was referring to your opening remark; I meant that the quadratic formula does not hold in fields of characteristic $2$.