# Number of irreducible cubics over a field of $n$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 25 Exercise C4.

> How many irreducible cubics are there over a field of $n$ elements?

1. Total number of monic cubics $x^3 + ax + bx + c$: $n^3$.
2. For monic reducible cubics in the form of $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$, either all, only two, or none of $a, b, c$ are the same. Therefore the total number of such cases is $\displaystyle {n\choose 1} + 2{n\choose 2} + {n\choose 3}$.
3. Per [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1571856/120815), the number of *monic irreducible quadratics* is $n(n-1)/2$. This suggests for monic reducible cubics in the form of $(x^2+ax+b)(x+c)$ where $x^2+ax+b$ is irreducible, there are $n^2(n-1)/2$ cases.

Hence, the total number of

*Monic reducible* cubics:

$\displaystyle\quad R = {n\choose 1} + 2{n\choose 2} + {n\choose 3} + \frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}$

*Monic irreducible* cubics:

$\displaystyle\quad n^3 - R$

*Irreducible* cubics:

$\displaystyle\quad(n-1)\left(n^3 - R\right)$.

Correct?

Comment: I think everything you wrote is correct. I can't find any mistakes.

Comment: Do you know that with $a(d)$ the number of monic irreducibles $\in \Bbb{F}_q[x]$ of degree $d$, by unique factorization $$\prod_{d\ge 1}\frac1{(1-T^d)^{a(d)}}=\prod_{f \in F_q[x] \ monic \ irreducible}(1+\sum_{k\ge 1} T^{\deg(f^k)})=\sum_{g\in F_q[x]\ monic} T^{\deg(g)}= \sum_{d\ge 0} q^d T^d$$ From which $a(d)= \frac1d \sum_{l | d} \mu(l) q^{d/l}$

Comment: This and related questions have been asked and answered on our site many times. The two that I selected contain a slight generalization (one of the answers has the most general formula also) as well as an approach like yours for the particular case of cubics. If those leave anything unclear, please comment, and we can reconsider. Do also check other threads linked to the chosen ones (see the right margins for a list). Plenty of information there.

Comment: And +1 for showing your work, making it easier to select appropriate duplicate targets.