# Number of irreducible polynomial over a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Find the number of irreducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ over a field with five elements.

Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** As this result is given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-p-over-finite-fields) answer.

The number of irreducible monic polynomials of degree $n$ (only when $n$ is prime) over the field of characteristic $p$ is $\frac{p^n-p}{n}$. In your case $p=5$ and $n=2$

Alternately Gauss gave the following result,

The number of irreducible monic polynomials of
degree $n$ over $F_q$ is given by $$N_q(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)q^{n/d}$$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius function.

For a proof see [this.](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111101001/downloads/Lecture11.pdf)

Comment: I think this answer is not really useful for anybody that might actually ask the question. In fact it may mislead somebody into believing the significantly  more complicated result is *needed.* (I will not add a second downvote though.)

Answer (score 6):

Hints.

1. Count the number of monic quadratic polynomials, irreducible or not.
2. Count the number of products $(x-a)(x-b)$, remembering that $a$ might equal $b$.
3. Subtract.