# Number of irreducible divisors of $x^{p^q}-x\in \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

For primes p,q I am trying to find the number of irreducible factors of $f(x)=x^{p^q}-x\in \mathbb{F}_p$. My first thought was that since q is prime there is no proper subfield 
$$\mathbb{F}_p \subset E \subset \mathbb{F}_{p^q}$$
therefore for every root $\alpha$ of $f$, $F(\alpha)=\mathbb{F}_p$ or $F(\alpha)=\mathbb{F}_{p^q}$. Hence if $m_\alpha(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ then $deg(m_\alpha)=1$ or $deg(m_\alpha)=q$ since $[\mathbb{F}_{p^q}:\mathbb{F}_p]=q$.
But, this means that all irreducible polynomials of
$$\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)/(x^p-x)$$
are of degree $q$ which means that $q\vert (p^q-p)$ which is usually not the case.
So my argument is incorrect and i dont know the correct one. Will be glad for a hint

Comment: They can also be of degree $1$, such as $x$ or $x-1$. For a concrete example, [$x^{3^2}-x = x(x+1)(x+2)(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + x + 2)(x^2 + 2x + 2)$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%5Bx%5E9-x,+Modulus+-%3E+3%5D).

Comment: You can find your answer at the accepted answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-prime-degree-p-over-finite-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat’s little theorem tells you that it *is* usually (ehm, always) the case that
$$
q\mid (p^q-p)
$$

Comment: @yoni No problems, it happens! The key is that $q$ is prime!